# express.js app throws no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Here is a express server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static('public'));
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'someuser',
  password : 'somepassword',
  database: 'some_database'
});

connection.connect();
app.get('/users/authenticate', function(req, res){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send({test:"test"});
res.end();

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Now when i issue a get request to this API, i get nothing in response tab of network console though response code is 200 ok. Please shed some light. I expect JSON data here.
Here is what i get in my console:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `i get nothing in response tab of network console though it shows a OK response in network console` well, which one is it?

Comment: response code is 200 ok but no data is received. I expect a json data here.

Comment: It looks like you're performing a cross-domain request (your HTML page is served from localhost but your AJAX request is sent to `api.avcls.com:3000`). What does your console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
app.get('/users/authenticate', function(req, res){
    res.json({foo:'bar'});
});
```

Also, if you are doing this across different domains, you will need to setup CORS.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
}
```

...and if you are attempting to test CORS from a localhost, you will need to open Chrome with some security disabled. If you are on a Mac, it is done with the following command. Just make sure Chrome is closed before you run it.

```
`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`
```

Comment: ok made a setup for CORS as you described and it worked. Now my question is that why did it at all returned 200ok if the request was not entertained by server?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. I've run into the same issue before and just figured it was the browser geeking out.

Comment: All SO daddies - help us here :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok. I am getting {test:"test"} both from browser and also using

```
curl http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate
```

Comment: this api resides on a remote server. will it make a difference?

Comment: cant really say whats wrong, are you hitting the /users/authenticate uri ?

Comment: yes. When i hit the same with browser, it shows me the desired result. But when done through a ajax request, it returns no response !!